# How to implement a multi-level sort in comparator in Backbone.js/underscore.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

Imagine a Model/Collection like:

```
var AModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        a: 'a string',
        b: 'another string',
        c: 'yet another string'
    }
});

var ACollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: AModel,
    comparator: function(amodel) {
        ...
    }
});
```

How could I write a comparator to implement a multi-level sort?  I'd like to sort by `AModel`'s `a` attribute, then by its `b` attribute, and then by its `c` attribute.

I've hacked together a comparator that looks something like this, but I want to know if there is a better/smarter way?

```
comparator: function(amodel) {
    var s = '',
        assumed_max_length_of_any_attribute = 30;

    s += amodel.get('a');
    while (s.length < assumed_max_length_of_any_attribute) {
        s += ' ';
    }

    s += amodel.get('b');
    while (s.length < assumed_max_length_of_any_attribute) {
        s += ' ';
    }

    s += amodel.get('c');
    while (s.length < assumed_max_length_of_any_attribute) {
        s += ' ';
    }

    return s;
}
```

Then, `s` becomes properly padded with spaces and should be in "lexical" order with multiple levels.  But it all feels very gross compared to the beauty of python's stable multi-level sort (if somehow the above had analogous equivalents in python):

```
collection.sort(key=lambda x: x.get('c'))
collection.sort(key=lambda x: x.get('b'))
collection.sort(key=lambda x: x.get('a'))
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The backbone documentation says:

> Comparator function can be defined as either a sortBy (pass a function
>   that takes a single argument), or as a sort (pass a comparator
>   function that expects two arguments).

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-comparator

You could use the second way and implement your comparison based on two elements given.

Maybe something like this:

```
helper: function (c1, c2) {
    if (c1 < c2) return -1;
    if (c1 > c2) return +1;
    return 0;
}
comparator: function (model1, model2) {
    return _.reduce(["c", "b", "a"], function (acc, comp) {
        return acc !== 0 ? acc : this.helper(model1[comp], model2[comp])
    }, 0);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this feature was introduced in backbone 0.9, a week ago. It worth reading the version history.

Comment: It'd be good to see someones implementation for it using this new method too though

Comment: I added an implementation above.

Comment: Thanks!  A nice use of _.reduce() too, wouldn't have thought to use that.

Comment: I can get this to work on 2 of the 3 passed criteria. I'm sorting a collection on 3 values (2 of which I have a method converting the value to a 0-2 index to determine priority) then date. 

The first 2 criteria work perfectly but the items aren't then sorted by date.

Comment: I guess that model1[comp] shoulb de replaced by model.get(comp)